# How to replace the first letter of a string using SQL and Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database column of `varchar(191)` with strings in the database. We need to replace the first letter of every string with an "E". So for instance, we have:

- `Cuohvi-AQNqalPq8zdr1cOA`

Needs to be changed to

- `Euohvi-AQNqalPq8zdr1cOA`

Do you know how we can achieve this in Postgres with a SQL query? It needs to be updated for the whole table.

Comment: Method: Concatenate 'E' and the substring of the column data after the first character. I didn't say it would be cheap! It is certain to work in every sql database  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) use `overlay()`:

```
UPDATE the_table SET the_field = overlay(the_field placing 'E' from 1 for 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of the `CONCAT` function and the `RIGHT` function with an argument of `-1`.

```
SELECT CONCAT('E', RIGHT('Cuohvi-AQNqalPq8zdr1cOA', - 1))
FROM yourtable

SELECT CONCAT('E', RIGHT(yourfield, - 1))
FROM yourtable
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e198b05f02283137afc39c24bb6c788d